# Bypass Validation Rule because of After Insert Trigger

Tags: trigger, validation, insert

I have two objects A__C and B__c where B__C is the child of A__C. we have a before inert,before trigger on A__c and all after triggers on B__c. Basically the after trigger is used to calculate or roll up the count of A__c which is also a lookup apart from parent.

Now there is a validation rule which restricts certain users to edit A__c except certain profiles and owner and alternate owner(Let's say u1__c) which is a lookup to user. However, when alternate owner tries to create child record B__c the after insert exception custom field validation error throws up.

I fixed it by setting a boolean flag(Skip__c) on A__C and made it true on before trigger present on A__c and add it in validation rule at the end like &&NOT(SKIP__c) which works now fine. However, i want the validation rule to work again and restrict other users to edit A__c in case where i tried to create a workflow rule to set the flag as false if it is true. However, it seems the validation rule does not work and even if the user does not satisfy any criteria in rule still he can edit the record A__c.

Could you please help?

Comment: Why are you using a validation rule to restrict who can edit the object? Would it be possible to use profile permissions and sharing rules instead?

Comment: When you say, you have a validation ; Is it via validation rule or a trigger ? And what are you looking to achieve should this rule be bypassed only when count is being updated?

Comment: @martin: The object is having Public read and Write at OWD level and this can not be changed. Also, the profile is having Read/Edit access which is not changed.

Comment: @Amit: validation is enforced at object or configuration level and it is not currently thrown from Trigger. I was able to find out root cause as the other master object field A__c which is a look up also(from where roll up is done using after trigger) does not give access to the current user as the user is not owner or alternate owner